# Need helping understand what this script is doing

Tags: shell-script

```bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo Usage: $0 DIRECTORY
   exit 1

elif [ ! -d $1 ]
then
   echo $1 is not a directory
   exit 2
fi
directory=$1
cd $directory
files=*
echo $directory
echo $files
exit 0
```

Got this far trying to break it down

- `$#` is the number of remaining arguments
- `[` is the test command
- `-ne` is the numeric "not equals" operator.
  So `if [ $# -ne 1 ]` is testing if there is exactly one argument (left).

In your second example:

- `!` means not
- `-d` means output directory
- `$1` is the first remaining argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying the script you provided to `shellcheck.com` and fixing all the issues found by it:

- Missing she-bang
- Many missing quotes
- Ensure that if the cd fails the script also fails
- An assignment of `files=*` is equivalent to `files="*"` which means the variable is going to contain only an `*` character. Solved by getting the whole list of files assigned to `files`.

The script gets to be:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]                  # check that there is one argument given.
then
    echo "Usage: $0 DIRECTORY"     # inform the user how to use the script.
    exit 1
elif [ ! -d "$1" ]                 # check that the argument is a directory.
then
    echo "$1 is not a directory"   # inform the user if on error.
    exit 2
fi

directory=$1
cd "$directory" || exit 3          # change to that directory
set -- *                           # get a list of files inside
files="$*"
echo "$directory"                  # Print the name
echo "$files"                      # Print the file list.
exit 0
```

There are still some higher level issues, but the script is being explained on the comments.

The whole script lists the files inside a directory.

Comment: Errors to `stderr`. Don't start a line for `echo` with a user defined variable as it could start with `-n` or something equally irritating. `printf '%s\n' ...` would be better

Comment: @roaima Of course, those (and others) errors are part of the _some higher level issues_ but the script is exactly how it should be from correcting **only** the errors that shellcheck found ... and adding some comments to answer the question of the OP.